# Content-type for application includes charset

Tags: json, rest, curl, character-encoding, content-type

I was writing a piece of simple Java code that calls a REST API to mimic the same I did with curl. The curl command sends a POST request to a login end-point:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
"username": "MicroStrategy",
"password": "MyPassword",
"loginMode": 1
}' 'https://env-792.customer.cloud.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api/auth/login'
```

When this succeeds, you get back a 204 HTTP response code and a token as an HTTP Header.

Now, with the following code, I did not get the same result and instead got a HTTP 200 and no token and no body.

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"username\": \"MicroStrategy\", \"password\": \"MyPassword\", \"loginMode\": 1}");
Request urlrequest = new Request.Builder()
   .url("https://env-792.customer.cloud.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api/auth/login")
   .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
   .post(body)
   .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Response urlresponse = client.newCall(urlrequest).execute();
```

In the process of trying to understand what I was doing wrong, I ran the request through a reverse proxy (I used "Charles") and realized that the content-type set by okhttp3 was including the charset for application/json:

```
POST /MicroStrategyLibrary/api/auth/login HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 63
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.8.0
Host: env-792.customer.cloud.microstrategy.com

{"username": "MicroStrategy", "password": "MyPassword", "loginMode": 1}
```

I verified that the matching curl statement also fails

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
"username": "MicroStrategy",
"password": "MyPassword",
"loginMode": 1
}' 'https://env-792.customer.cloud.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api/auth/login'
```

Is this a known issue? (it is my understanding that the RFC for content type only allows charset for the text/* content-types; but I'm no expert in that area!)

What can I do to overwrite the Content-Type to remove the charset part?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your JSON data to [`RequestBody.create()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html#create-okhttp3.MediaType-java.lang.String-) using a Java `String`.  Per the OkHttp documentation:

> ```
> public static RequestBody create(@Nullable
>                                  MediaType contentType,
>                                  String content)
> ```
>
> Returns a new request body that transmits content. **If contentType is non-null and lacks a charset, this will use UTF-8.**

So, the method you are using intentionally forces UTF-8, so it is likely adding the `charset` attribute to match.

Try using one of the other `create()` methods that takes a `byte[]` or `okio.ByteString` as input instead of a Java `String`.  They are not documented as forcing UTF-8, since they are taking raw bytes as input, so it is the caller's responsibility to specify a `charset` only if one is actually needed:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"username\": \"MicroStrategy\", \"password\": \"MyPassword\", \"loginMode\": 1}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, okio.ByteString.encodeUtf8("{\"username\": \"MicroStrategy\", \"password\": \"MyPassword\", \"loginMode\": 1}"));
```

Comment: I confirm that using the `create()` with a `byte[]` input worked. I don't like to use workaround, but that'll be enough for me at this point! :)